# An internal error has occurred on context sync with any Excel operations

Tags: excel, office-js

I have multiple Excel workbooks that are causing the Excel API to throw `An internal error has occurred` on the first context sync we do in our application.

The excel code looks like this

```
  let range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();    
  range.load('address');
  try {
    await ctx.sync();
  } catch (err) { 
    // log error
  }
  return range;
```

Nothing too exciting. I've tried running other Excel operations first that get settings and get named ranges, but the same thing happens. Throws `An internal error has occurred` when syncing. This leads me to believe there is an issue with these workbooks and they're in a bad state that office-js doesn't like.

What kinds of things should I be looking for when looking at the workbook? The only time I've seen similar behaviour was with a massive number of named ranges.