# Error on excel context sync in a addin dialog box

Tags: office-js

From my excel task pane, I am showing a dialog box from the main web page using the below code.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + "/Sample.html", { height: 50, width: 23 });
```

In Sample.html, i have the below code, which throws an error 'An internal error has occurred.' The control does goes inside document.ready block. Please let me know how to use office.js methods in a addin dialog box.

```
        Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Excel.run(function (ctx) {
                var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();  
                sheet.getRange("A1").values = [["test"]];

                return ctx.sync()
                    .then(function () {
                    })
                    .then(ctx.sync);
            })
            .catch(errorHandler);
        });
    }
```

There already a similar issue exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614484/an-internal-error-has-occurred-on-context-sync-with-any-excel-operations), but it is not related to dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use two Office JavaScript APIs in a dialog: `isSetSupported` and `messageParent`. See the Important note about 1/3 of the way down this page: [Dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Thanks Rick for pointing out to the documentation.